# Change rendered html

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a dll thats rendering a div at the top of my page and I need to remove. Is it possible to edit the html that is about to be rendered, so that i can remove the div from the html before its displayed:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // setup a TextWriter to capture the markup
    TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    // render the markup into our surrogate TextWriter
    base.Render(htw);

    // get the captured markup as a string
    string pageSource = tw.ToString();

    // render the markup into the output stream verbatim
    writer.Write(pageSource);

    // remove the viewstate field from the captured markup
    //string viewStateRemoved = Regex.Replace(pageSource,
    //    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"__VIEWSTATE\" id=\"__VIEWSTATE\" value=\".*?\" />",
    //    "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // the page source, without the viewstate field, is in viewStateRemoved
    // do what you like with it
}
```

Comment: You could convert the `div` into `asp:panel`, and then toggle its `Visible` property.

Comment: I have updated the method to show you what i used, this was within a usercontrol on the page. it only let me remove the html from the user control. i need to remove the div from above the body tag.